# WiFi "like" calling for Verizon users?

Tags: wi-fi, verizon

I am using Verizon and coverage is poor at my home. Is there any app or service that would allow me to use WiFi calling while at home yet still keep my Verizon assigned phone number? I don't want to use a service that requires callers to use the same app to receive calls. Something like Skype works well except when I make calls through Skype, callers see my Skype number rather than my Verizon assigned phone number.

Built-in WiFi calling would be the best but who knows when Verizon will actually implement that.

I am using Android 5.1.1 on a Galaxy Note 5.

Comment: Calling from within whatsapp is no option either? Nowadays most people seem to have whatsapp installed

Comment: I am looking for a solution that allows calling all phones including landlines and non-smartphones